# "very much" modifying adjectives

Tags: adverbs, participial-adjectives

> [Past participles that have become established as adjectives can, like
> most English adjectives, be modified by the adverb *very*. However,
> there is rarely any objection to the use of an intervening adverb, no
> matter how the past participle is functioning. Such use often occurs
> in edited writing](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/very)
>
> *We were **very much relieved** to find the children asleep.  They were very greatly excited by the news.  I feel very badly cheated*

Yet, the [OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/very_1?q=very) reads

> *Very* is used with adjectives, past participles used as adjectives, and adverbs, but notice this use: *I’m **very much afraid** that your
> son may be involved in the crime.*

Aren't these excerpts contradictory?

Secondly, *afraid* being an adjective, why can't it modified by *very*?

Comment: No, I don't think they are contradictory. I couldn't find that exact sentence in the OLD link, but both say that an adverb _can_ be used between _very_ and an adjective.  You can say _very afraid_, though _very frightened_ would probably be more idiomatic.

Comment: I'd say that "very" is modifying  "much".